# How to get angular 5 route segments from ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular

I am using the latest angular5 version. I have the following coded routes (note that fruits and veggies are NOT parameters:

```
/fruits/item
/veggies/basket
```

Note that fruits is a parent route, and I have multiple children routes in an array (item is just one of them). 'veggies' is also a parent route. 'basket' is one of the 'child routes' in an array under the veggies route.

How can I use "ActivatedRoute", though how do I get access to the first "fruits" or "veggies" segment of the route? I want to check it and log it out to the console.

Assume Activated route is already injected into the variable "route".

Looking for something like this pseudocode(if it is correct)

```
showRouteRoot() {
   console.log(this.route.getFirstSegmentNameInRoute()) 
// expected output is fruits OR veggies. 
// If this can't be done in one line of code, 
// multiple lines is an acceptable answer
}
```

I've tried:

```
console.log(this.route.snapshot.url.split('/'));
```

This yields problems.

```
console.log(this.route.url)
```

This shows me some AnonymousSubject

```
console.log(this.route.parent.url)
```

This shows me a BehaviorSubject

Comment: have you tried `console.log(route.snapshot.url[0].path);` ?

Comment: That does not log out the first part, only the end of the url path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ActivatedRoute` provided a member `pathFromRoot` which let developers to get full activedroutes from root, refer [to the docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#members).

For your situation, you can use below code block to achieve it:

```
this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[1].url.subscribe(val => console.log(val[0].path));
```

Mention that currently the result of `pathFromRoot` contains a empty route(first element of the `ActivatedRoute[]`) which means for the path `''`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it this way :

```
let url = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url.join().split(',')
console.log(url[0]);
```

If you want to retrieve the parent route, then have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483570/angular-2-get-parent-activated-route).

Comment: am getting split is not a property of this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url

Comment: it still says property "split" does not exist on urlsegment. This is angular 5.

Comment: So it only says "item" or "basket". It does not say "fruits" or "veggies". The way I have the routes defined, is there is a parent route (fruits or veggies), and I have an array of "children" routes under that.

Comment: Look at the url in my answer to retrieve parent route. That should help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Router like...

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot.url.split('/').at(-1)
```

No need of ActivatedRoute.