# Angular Get last part of url

Tags: angular

I want to get the last part of my url for example from `/item/:id/edit` I want to get `edit` or `/edit`.

I found [this Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684409/how-to-get-angular-5-route-segments-from-activatedroute) but this doesnt work because I want to run this Code in the parent component and the whole url I get from this Code is `/item/:id`.

How can I get the last part from it?

Comment: check this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483570/angular-2-get-parent-activated-route?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Isn`t this a solution if I wanted to get the parent url? I can get this to with my linked question but I want the last part of the url

Comment: if you don't need to subscribe on url changes you can get it from window.location.href. Something like: window.location.href split('/').[window.location.href split('/').lenght -1]

Comment: What do you mean of `parent` component?

Comment: Using `private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute` should always give you the current path, no matter where you are

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use ActivatedRoute interface, it contains the router state tree
within the angular app’s memory.

The `parent` property represents the parent of the route in the router state tree,
while the `snapshot` property is the current snapshot of the route and `url` is an
observable of the URL segments and it matched by this route.

**Step 1**: Import ActivatedRoute

```js
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

**Step 2**: Inject ActivatedRoute in constructor.

```js
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

**Step 3**: Call it in Oninit lifecycle hook

```js
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
        
           ngOnInit() {
              this.route.parent.snapshot.url[2].path;
           }
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Answer (score 22):

I have the solution for getting the last part of URL

```
url = '/item/:id/edit'
url.split('/').pop();
```

**Explain:**

1. `.split('/')` means split the string  which
   is separated by '/' to an array of substrings
2. `.pop()` means removes the last element of an
   array, and returns that element
3. `.split('/').pop()` means split the
   string which is separated by '/' to an array of substrings then
   removes the last element of an array and return that element

**I hope this help**

Comment: This fails when there's a querystring parameter attached to it; because that would also be included.

Comment: A safer solution, which covers a possible presence of query string in the URL, would be `url.split('?')[0].split('/').pop()`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to get the URL part being in a parent component, you have to wait until the navigation occurs.

#### Get the last URL part from a parent component

```js
router.events
  .pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map((event: NavigationEnd) => event.url)
  )
  .subscribe(url => {
    const lastUrlSegment = url.split('?')[0].split('/').pop()
  });
```

Where `router` is an injected [Angular Router service](https://angular.io/api/router/Router). Here `url.split('?')[0]` returns the URL part without query parameters in case they exist, then `split('/').pop()` returns the last URL segment without the `/` character.

In case you'd like to

#### Get the last URL part from the child component

You could do that synchronously

```js
const lastUrlSegment = router.url.split('?')[0].split('/').pop()
```

Where `router` is an injected [Angular Router service](https://angular.io/api/router/Router). Pay attention, that under the child component I mean the one, rendered by the last URL segment we're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
Use the below code.

My url is - localhost:4200/home/user/address

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.url)
    console.log(this.router.url.split('/')[0]);
    console.log(this.router.url.split('/')[1]);
    console.log(this.router.url.split('/').pop());
  }
}

Output -
>home/user/address
>home
>user
>address
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation on how and why your approach works and how it differs from the other answers given.

Answer (score 2):

This is what's working for me on `Angular v15`

```
export class OrderComponent {

  requestId: string | null = null;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  }

}
```

In the `Routes` I've

```
  {
    path: 'order/:id',
    component: OrderComponent,
    data: {
      breadcrumb: '',
    },
  },
```

Comment: The most elegant way to get parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is you can split the current url on the basis of '/', it will convert the url into an array and you can get any part you want.
See the code snippet below:

```
url =window.location.href;

console.log(this.url.split('/')[4]);
```

Comment: I actually had to use this. I know it's not Angular-like, but the last section of the URL isn't being passed in the route for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you will need to use `ActivatedRoute` to do this, please see code example below:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
   var url = this.route.parent.snapshot.url[2].path;

   console.log(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url from following object

```
private router: Router
```

it has url property
`this.router.url`

you can get the last part of url via following code

```
this.router.url.substring(this.router.url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```