# Angular access component route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I want to access a component's routing URL that is **not** the current url and store it in a service. So basically if my component is `parentComponent` and has `childComponent` then the URL of the child component is

```
/parentComponent/childComponent
```

If I navigate to the above URL and call `this.router.url` in `parentComponent`'s `ngOnInit` then it correctly returns `/parentComponent/childComponent`. How do I get just `/parentComponent`, i.e. the route to the component itself, from the router within the parent component?

Comment: This might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483570/angular-2-get-parent-activated-route

Answer (score 0):

this.router.parent.url will return parent url and it's params.

Comment: Thank you but I'm looking for a more universal approach that also works with nested children